# How can I search any item in many list very efficiently?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a problem to find very efficient way to search birthday in many list.

Here is my horoscope_dates function

```
def calculate_horoscope_dates(start, end):
    horoscope_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%m-%d-%Y")
    horoscope_end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%m-%d-%Y")
    horoscope_interval = [horoscope_start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (horoscope_end-horoscope_start).days)]

    string_interval = []
    for date in horoscope_interval:
        #convert datetime to str
        string_interval.append(date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
        # remove minutes and seconds from date
        string_interval = [i.lstrip("0") for i in string_interval]

    return string_interval
```

Here is my horoscope list shown below

```
aries = calculate_horoscope_dates("3-21-2020", "4-20-2020")
taurus = calculate_horoscope_dates("4-20-2020", "5-21-2020")
gemini = calculate_horoscope_dates("5-21-2020", "6-22-2020")
...
```

aries list is defined shown below. Other list is the same as a defined list.

```
['21-03-2020',
 '22-03-2020',
 '23-03-2020',....]
```

Here is my input part

```
month = input("Enter your month of birth: " )
day = input("Enter your day of birth: " )
birthday = day + "-0" + month + "-2020"
birthday
```

I can do search process via for loop but I think it is not very efficient way to do the process because I can write repeatly this code show below.

```
for birthday_date in aries:
    if birthday in birthday_date:
        print("Aries")
```

What I want to ask is learn how to find birthday in many list very efficiently.

*Edit*

```
horoscope_dates = {"aries": aries,
                   "taurus": taurus,
                   "gemini": gemini,
                   "cancer": cancer,
                   "leo": leo,
                   "virgo": virgo,
                   "libra": libra,
                   "scorpio": scorpio,
                   "sagittarius": sagittarius,
                   "capricorn": capricorn,
                   "aquarius": aquarius,
                   "pisces": pisces,
                   }



for h in horoscope_dates:
    start, end = horoscope_dates[h] <- Error
    if start <= birthday < end:
        print(h)
```

There is an issue there (ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2))

Comment: You can keep the dates as `datetime.date` objects and perform comparing operations with `>` and  `<` like in math.

Comment: @Asocia I edited my post.

Comment: The loop + if-statement are redundant. You can replace both lines with just `if birthday in aries:`. Also note that there's really no way around a bunch of if-statements in this case. You can store the dates in something like a set to have faster lookups, but you'll always need something like `if birthday in aries`.

Comment: @bnaecker Nope, there is no need to store all the dates in a given range. Hence, no need for multiple if statements. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859499/13123836).

Comment: @Asocia Sure, you can store the dates as a range in a single container. You still need one check for each container/range. That's all I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import date

horoscope_dates = {"aries": (date(2020, 3, 21), date(2020, 4, 20)),
                   "taurus": (date(2020, 4, 20), date(2020, 5, 21)),
                   "gemini": (date(2020, 5, 21), date(2020, 6, 22)),
                   }

month = int(input("Enter your month of birth: "))
day = int(input("Enter your day of birth: "))
year = 2020
birthday = date(year, month, day)

for horoscope, (start, end) in horoscope_dates.items():
    if start <= birthday < end:
        print(horoscope)
        break
```

Comment: @TonyBrand The error was the ellipsis (`...`) symbol. It would be nice if it can be used as a placeholder everywhere but anyways, removed it. It should work now.

Comment: Oh actually you never saw the ellipsis as I removed it immediately. What's the error then?

Comment: I don't want to define date in each holoscope in dict. I just use list in each key of dict. How can I rearrange for loop.

Comment: Oh, I saw your edit just now. It didn't work because you copied my loop and expect it to work with your data. You are asking for **efficiency**, and this is an efficient way of doing it. You shouldn't create all the dates in a year. Just starting and ending date of each horoscope is enough.

Comment: Allright. How can I rearrange for loop because I want to use date list in dic.

Comment: `for h, dates in horoscope_dates.items(): if birthday in dates: print(h)`

Comment: Thank you for your response.